# How can I make image_crop with the Galleria jQuery plugin different if the image is wider vs taller?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gallery, image-gallery, galleria

Essentially I want to change a variable for image crop depending on the dimensions of each image in the gallery. If an image's height is greater than the width I want to switch to the height crop, else keep the width crop. I am using the Galleria plugin so far I have this code:

```
if ($(image).width() > $(image).height()){  
var upordown = "width"
} else {        
var upordown = "height"
}
```

An the variable is here and is part of the list of options for Galleria:

```
 image_crop : upordown,
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a way to always fit the image inside the container, without cropping? Try to set `image_crop` (or `imageCrop` in the latest version) to `false`.

**Edit:** you can listen to the `loadfinish` event and set options according to the image dimensions on the fly. You need to call `refreshImage` to apply the changes.

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    extend: function() {
        var gallery = this,
            landscape;
        this.bind('loadfinish', function(e) {
            landscape = e.imageTarget.width >= e.imageTarget.height 
                ? 'width' : 'height';
            gallery.setOptions( 'imageCrop', landscape ).refreshImage();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem it just fits the image inside the container without cropping. I want the cropping choice to be different depending on the image. If the image is portrait no crop or 'height' crop and if the image is landscape set crop to true or 'width' crop. Thanks for trying to help though. Hopefully someone can come up with an if statement that will do the trick.

Comment: Interesting if I set the default for 'imageCrop' as 'height' then insert your code, It switches 'imageCrop' to 'width' but instead of doing it only for landscape images it does it for them all. Is there somewhere else I need to put 'refreshImage();'? Also the first image loaded in the gallery isn't affected unless I click forward to the next image then back, then it switches to landscape as it should.

Is the fact I'm using the classic theme affecting the issue? should the code go in the theme file somewhere?

Thanks for all your help I think your getting close to a fix.

Answer (score 1):

taking from David's example I feel like this is the best option. It's not really really smooth but it helps with the issue that Lee Tindell was talking about.

```
this.bind('image', function(e) {
    var imageW = e.imageTarget.width;
    var imageH = e.imageTarget.height;

    if (imageH > imageW) {
        landscape = 'height';
    } else if (imageH < imageW) {
        landscape = true;
    }

    this.setOptions({ imageCrop: landscape }).refreshImage();
});
```